# Printing value of a variable as a object name python

Tags: python

Here goes an newbie question on python. 
From the following function

```
def singlereader(url, linkGlue):
    d = feedparser.parse(url)
    tmp = []
    for item in d.entries:
        tmp.append(item.linkGlue) # line 5
    return tmp
```

how would i use the variable value as the object name for "item"
In line 5, i want to use the value of "linkGlue" variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, use:

```
getattr(item, linkGlue)
```

in place of

```
item.linkGlue
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get here is to leverage [operator.attrgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) or using the builtin [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
def singlereader(url, linkGlue):
    from operator import attrgetter
    d = feedparser.parse(url)
    tmp = []
    for item in d.entries:
        #tmp.append(attrgetter(linkGlue)(item)) # line 5
        tmp.append(getattr(item, linkGlue))
    return tmp
```